# Проблема с многопрцессорностью в питоне

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, multiprocessing

У меня есть графический интерфейс созданный с помощью Tkinter. [image: Графический интерфейс]

При открытии видео файла, я открываю окно, которое выводит видео с помощью библиотеки opencv. Мне нужно, чтобы в одном процессе работал графический интерфейс, а потом создавался еще один процесс, который при выборе файла обрабатывал видео. И мне не ясно как поместить данные задания в разные процессы.
Хотелось бы понять как это сделать с помощью библиотеки multiprocessing.

Comment: что такое "данные задания". Если забыть о tkinter, opencv, то как бы вы запустили функцию в другом Питон-процессе, передав ей допустим два целых числа из основного потока? Создайте минимальный, но полный пример кода, который вашу проблему показывает (лучше начните с маленького искусственного примера, чтобы с multiprocessing модулем освоиться) [mcve]